# ActiveModel first argument in form cannot contain nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I want to create form without using Active Record, I'm following the Ruby on Rails tutorial, and use Active Model, so I have a model

```
class GoodsPurchase

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :phone, :name, :email

  validates_presence_of :phone
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :email, :with =>  /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    super
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

then I have controller

```
class Market::Desktop::Vision::GoodsPurchaseController < CatalogController

  domain_layout 'page_screen'

  def create_message
    @goods = GoodsPurchase.new message_params
    if @goods.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:goods).permit(:phone, :name, :email)
  end
end
```

And view

```
<%= form_for @goods, url: goods_purchase_create_message_url, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
                <%= f.label :Phone, class: "label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "int", placeholder: "+7 (   ) 123-45-67", :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <%= f.label :Name, class: "label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: "int", placeholder: "Oleg Petrov", :required => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <%= f.label :Email, class: "label" %>
                <%= f.text_field :email, class: "int", placeholder: "example@example.ru", :required => true %>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="articul_for_order" class="js_articul_for_order">
            <div class="row">
                <%= recaptcha_tags %>
            </div>
            <button type="" class="btn btn_middle btn_blue2">Order callback`enter code here`</button>
            <%= f.submit "Callback", class: 'btn btn_middle btn_blue2' %>
        <% end %>
```

And in route.rb I wrote `post "goods_purchase/create_message"`
And after that I have this error `first argument in form cannot contain nil` I don't know why and what I have to do with it

Comment: in your form try `goods_purchase_create_message_path`
and in your routes: `post "goods_purchase/create_message", to: "post "goods_purchase#create_message" `

Comment: Thanks, I  found a mistake. I forgot to write in the main controller before_action ->{ @goods = ::GoodsPurchase.new }